# Exponent of derivative squared

Tags: analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

There is a well-known formal relation
$$e^{y\partial_x} f(x)=f(x+y)$$
Is there anything similar for operator $e^{\partial_x ^2}$?

Comment: How do you define this operator? Is it similar to $e^{y\partial_x f(x)}$?

Answer (score 2):

*Comment.*
The first means
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{y^j}{j!} f^{(j)}(x) = f(x+y)
$$
Called "Taylor series".
The second one would be
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{1}{j!}f^{(2j)}(x) = \text{ ?}
$$

Comment: Yes, sure. So perhaps this is also some kind of finite difference? Perhaps with some change of variables?